# Does Python have a shorthand notation for passing part of a list without copy?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I convert the below pseudocode to Python. Regarding specifically the parameter indicated as `1st half of A`, does Python have a mechanism like `A[1..n/2]` (another pseudocode shortcut I see from time to time) that **does not require copy** for passing part of a list as a parameter ?

```
Count(array A, length n)
    if n = 1 return 0
    else
        x = Count(1st half of A, n/2)
        y = Count(2nd half of A, n/2)
    return x + y
```

Without such a mechanism I will pass indices as necessary.

Comment: How can this function ever return anything other than `0`?

Comment: I'm less concerned about the pseudocode b/c it's incomplete. I omitted parts to focus only on `1st Half of A` in concept.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - In spite of the copy it creates, it's the best match. I ended up using `1st half of A = A[:len(A)//2]` and `2nd half of A = A[len(A)//2:]`. Thanks for teaching me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. You'll have to pass indices (or `slice` objects).

You could also write a `list` subclass that handles slices by returning "views" into the original list rather than copies. I've actually tackled this a few times and found it tricky to get completely right, but it's made much easier by the fact that your application doesn't need negative indexing, slice assignment, or the skip parameter. Here's a quick try:

```
class ListWithAView(list):

    class ListView(object):
        def __init__(self, list, start, stop, step):
            self.list  = list
            self.start = start
            self.stop  = stop
            self.step  = step

        def __iter__(self):
            for i in xrange(self.start, self.stop, self.step):
                yield self.list[i]

        def __len__(self):
            return (self.stop - self.start) / self.step

        def __getitem__(self, i):
            if isinstance(i, slice):
                return type(self)(self.list, (i.start or 0) + self.start,
                                  min(self.start + (i.stop or 0), self.stop),
                                  i.step * self.step if i.step else self.step)
            if isinstance(i, int) and i < len(self):
                return self.list[i+self.start]
            raise IndexError("invalid index: %r" % i)

        def __setitem__(self, i, v):
            if isinstance(i, int):
                self.list[i+self.start] = v
            else:
                raise IndexError("invalid index: %r" % i)

        def __repr__(self):
            return "<slice [%s:%s:%s] of list id 0x%08x>: %s" % (self.start, self.stop, self.step, id(self.list), self)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(list(self))

        __str__ = __repr__

    @property
    def view(self):
        return self.ListView(self, 0, len(self), 1)
```

The `view` property of this list subclass returns a `ListView` object that acts much like a list, but gets and sets the data in the underlying list rather than storing any items itself. The returned object initially refers to the entire list but can be sliced further if desired. For simplicity, negative steps aren't handled, and you can't do slice assignment, just single items.

Quick demo:

```
seq = ListViwthAView(range(100))
view = seq.view[10:20][5:7]
view[0] = 1337
print seq[15]    # 1337
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort of use `slice` objects here, but unfortunately there isn't a `__len__` method, so you have to  use `(s.start + s.stop)/2` to compute the length. Any time you wise to "materialise" the subarray (which of course creates a copy), you can use `A[s]`

```
def count(A, s=None):
    if s is None:
        s=slice(0, len(A))
    if s.start + 1  == s.stop:
        return 1
    else:
        x = count(A, slice(s.start, (s.start + s.stop)/2))
        y = count(A, slice((s.start + s.stop)/2, s.stop))
    return x + y

print count([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the best solution is to just pass the list and the indices as you suggested.

If you didn't need to index into the slices (for example, if just having iterators over the first and second halves of the list was sufficient), you could use the `islice` function from `itertools`. E.g.

```
from itertools import islice
half = (len(sequence) + 1) // 2
first_half = islice(sequence, half):
second_half = islice(sequence, half, len(sequence))
```